# How to test connection in web api with windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace pracRun.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class testdbController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<testdbController> _logger;

        public testdbController(ILogger<testdbController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "TestDatabaseConnection")]
        public IActionResult TestConnection()
        {
            string connectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-QTUJDO1\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True;";

            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    return Ok("Database connection successful.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, $"Error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to confirm the connection using get how do i do that or is it something wrong in my sql server, sql server management studio.

as you can see i used get and please inform me if connection string is wrong im using windows auth so no password need error says that

> Internal connection fatal error.

Comment: If you're just returning the exception message in your response, you're not getting the full details. If there's inner exceptions, you're missing them. You should implement an adequate logging interface to capture all the details from exceptions. To get started though, change `ex.Message` to `ex.ToString()` to see if that gives you more info.